# fitting an ARMAX model with box constraints in python

Tags: time-series, python, arima, fitting, statsmodels

I would like to identify some parameters from real world data (actually time series). After some mathematical manipulations of some equations describing my system, I conveniently end-up having a linear prediction equation :
$$y(t) =  \phi^T(t) \theta + \epsilon(t)\label{eq1}\tag{1}$$

Where $\theta$ is the vector containing the parameters I would like to estimate, $y(t)$ and $\phi(t)$ (respectively scalar and vector) depend on my data.

Unfortunately my system is quite disturbed, so much so that a Gaussian white noise does not model is not satisfactory to model $\epsilon(t)$. So I had to resort to something more complex than ordinary least squares and I tried fitting $\theta$ what I guess one might call "MAX" models (Moving Average with eXogenous input).

It is just fitting $\theta$ as in (\ref{eq1}), but instead of fitting $\theta$ with ordinary least squares I also try to fit the noise $\epsilon(t)$ with moving average in hope that the residual noise is white. To be explicit, my model is :

$$y(t) = \phi^T(t)\theta + \sum_{k=1}^{n_{ma}}\alpha_k \epsilon(t-k) + \epsilon(t)\label{eq2}\tag{2}$$

where $n_{ma}$ is the moving average depth and $\alpha_k$ is the k-th moving average coefficient.

I am now doing this in Python with statsmodels :

```
armax_model = ARIMA(
        b,
        exog=A[:, :],
        order=(0, 0, noise_model_order),
        seasonal_order=(0, 0, 0, 0),
        trend=None,
        enforce_stationarity=False,
        enforce_invertibility=False,
        concentrate_scale=False,
        trend_offset=1,
        dates=None,
        freq=None,
        missing="none",
        validate_specification=True,
    )
    fit_result = armax_model.fit(method="innovations")
```

where $b=\begin{bmatrix}y(0)\\y(1)\\...\\y(n)\end{bmatrix}$ and $A=\begin{bmatrix}\phi^T(0)\\\phi^T(1)\\...\\\phi^T(n)\end{bmatrix}$

This gives me relatively satisfactory results, but once in a while I get a crazy model. Here is an example of what I get afterwards when I use the identified $\theta$ to simulate my model against my actual system (note that I am **not** using \ref{eq1} for my simulation, but rather the physical equation from which I got \ref{eq1}):

[image]

Where the red curve is the simulation result.
In order to counter this exponential explosion problem I would simply like to add box constraints on my parameters because for instance, I know from theory that if $\theta[1]>0$ I can't have a numerical explosion like presented above.

More specifically I would like
$$10\leq\theta[0]\leq 50, \quad 1.000\leq\theta[1]\leq 100.000 \quad\text{ and }\quad 1.00\leq\theta[2]\leq 10.000$$

Unfortunately I wasn't able to apply constaints using statsmodels. Does anybody know how to perform this using statsmodels? or using another Python library?

Comment: Trying to understand your notation, could I interpret your model as $y_t=\beta x_t+\varepsilon_t$ where $x_t$ and thus $\beta$ may be vectors? And then you think $\varepsilon_t$ may follow a MA process? If so, then the MA part cannot produce patterns like yours, it must be due to the $\beta x_t$ part. (Having no scale for the $x$ axis obscures the picture a bit. Consider adding a scale there.)

Comment: @RichardHardy Hello, sorry I only just saw your comment. You understood my notations correctly. About the MA process, I might add the precision that my simulation was made without the MA process (just using $\phi(t)$ and $\theta$). Can't it yield something like I posted if the identified MA is unstable (I mean roots out of the unit circle)? I believe that the model and the MA are both stable or unstable together. I will edit my post to make my notations clearer and better explain the simulation. Thanks!

Comment: What is the scale of the $x$ axis? Regarding an unstable MA, I would need to think more but do not have the time right now...